# Silverlight debugging issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, silverlight, debugging

I am previously using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + Silverlight 3.0 and my application can be debugged correctly in VSTS 2008 (pressing F5 and then start debugging, my application is a traditional Silverlight application, i.e. an xap file embedded in html page).

I find when I upgrade to Silverlight 4.0 player, when debugging the same application, I met with the following error, any ideas what is wrong?

Unable to start debugging. The Silverlight managed debugging package isn't installed.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a problem a few people have encountered.  The solution is to install the latest silverlight developer runtime.

- Download Link: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188039
- Blog Post Detailing Problem: http://www.silverlightdev.net/?p=46

Comment: "The solution is to install the latest silverlight developer runtime." -- do I need to uninstall anything first?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to install the SL 4.0 developer package. The SL 3.0 developer package won't be able to debug SL 4.0 apps.

Comment: "SL 4.0 developer package" -- could you provide a Url please? Do I need to uninstall something for Silverlight 3?

Answer (score 2):

see solution for this problem posted [here](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/2010/04/16/unable-to-start-debugging-the-silverlight-managed-debugging-package-isnt-installed/).

You need to install the sl dev runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the following:

1. Make sure you using IE for your SL debugging.
2. Make sure your XAP is not being cached by IE (clearing your browsing history will remove any caching of the XAP).
3. When making changes to your Silverlight app, make sure you Clean your solution *first*, then rebuild the solution (again because of the XAP caching in the ClientBin folder).
4. Make sure you have Silverlight debugging enabled in your web application (you can check this by Right clicking the project and selecting Properties menu item).